# Sequelize "ignoreDuplicate: true" increments primaryKey?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I use sequelize in my node js project with Postgresql.
I am parsing some tables and updating its copy on my database. Imagine if I have 50000 records in external table in the moment, differences after 10 minutes are ~5%. I don't need to remove, only to create new ones. I used

```js
Model.bulkCreate(data, { ignoreDuplicates: true });
```

After 2 hours of working parsing in database count ~100 000 records, but id of the last ~1 000 000. Looks like `ignoreDuplicates: true` autoincrements id. How to avoid it without much cpu usage? Is `updateOnDuplicate` do the same thing?

The fastest way I found is

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

// some code
let existing = await Model.findAll({ attributes: [uniqColumn] });

let toCreate = _.differenceBy(data, existing, uniqColumn);
await Model.bulkCreate(toCreate);
```

Comment: can you show a SQL query that is corresponding t `Model.bulkCreate(data, { ignoreDuplicates: true });` (try to insert 1 row for instance)?

Comment: @Anatoly, `Executing (default): INSERT INTO "table_name" ("id","col1") VALUES (DEFAULT,'value1') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING "id","col1","col2", ...;` 
where col1 is uniq

Comment: `INSERT` looks good for me, It simply ignores all incoming rows that conflicts with existing ones by any unique constraint. Can you execute one such `INSERT` which contains the same unique column value manually and check if `id` was incremented?

Comment: @Anatoly, https://pastebin.com/0D5Seru0

Comment: @ВладимирГоворухин any updates? I have same problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PostgreSQL `sequence` to generate unique column then even if a row is not inserted due to conflicts the sequence value is still used.
See [next_val](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-sequence.html).

> Important: To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the same sequence, a nextval operation is never rolled back; that is, once a value has been fetched it is considered used and will not be returned again. This is true even if the surrounding transaction later aborts, or if the calling query ends up not using the value. For example an INSERT with an ON CONFLICT clause will compute the to-be-inserted tuple, including doing any required nextval calls, before detecting any conflict that would cause it to follow the ON CONFLICT rule instead. Such cases will leave unused "holes" in the sequence of assigned values. Thus, PostgreSQL sequence objects cannot be used to obtain "gapless" sequences.